# To use Certbot, packages from the EPEL repository need to be installed

Tags: ssl, cron, centos, lets-encrypt, certbot

I use certbot-auto for deploying Let's Encrypt SSL certificates, and I renew certificate with crontab -e like this:

`* 01 * * 1 /home/myname/certbot-auto --quiet`

It has an error message like the below:

`Bootstrapping dependencies for RedHat-based OSes...
    yum is /usr/bin/yum
    To use Certbot, packages from the EPEL repository need to be installed.
    Please enable this repository and try running Certbot again.`

I can't solve this error. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Under centos 7, provided the "extras" repo is enabled, you can just run `yum -y install epel-release`. I'm not sure this is available under Centos 6 (certainly won't hurt to try it). However, to install under CentOS 6 manually you would just run (as root, or using sudo):

```
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh epel-release-6*.rpm
```

Once the EPEL repository is installed on your system, try running `certbot` again. It should now be able to automatically install any required dependencies.